# Change text PHP

Tags: php, html, css, string, str-replace

I have to change the string "Rules of the game: You must guess in the least number of attempts a number between 0 and 99 randomly drawn from the system." with "The number entered is too small" only if the condition is met. The string therefore must be replaced in the same place where the initial one is. How can I change it?
I've already tried str_replace and preg_replace but it doesn't work.

Also I have to increment the variable x every time the user guesses the number wrong but I don't know how.

```html
<?php
    $indovina=7;
    $x = 0;
    $num=$_GET['num1'];
    if ($num<$indovina){
        echo "Il numero inserito e troppo piccolo";
    }
    else if ($num>$indovina){
        echo "Il numero inserito e' troppo grande";
    }
    if ($num==$indovina){
        echo "Bravo, hai indovinato";
    }
?>



<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
    <br><br>
    <center>
    <div class="card" style="width: 40rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
        <center>
            <font size=5>Gioco dell' Indovina Numero</font><br>
        </center>
        <div id="risultato" name="risultato">
        <center>
            <label size=3><b>Regole del gioco:</b> Si deve indovinare nel minor numero di tentativi un <br> numero compreso fra 0 e 99 estratto casualmente dal sistema.</label>
        </center>
        </div>
        <br>
        <form method="GET">
        <label id=tentativo>Tentativo n.1</label>
        <input type="number" id="num1" name="num1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tenta</button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <center>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the echo statements will output the string at the position in code

so you need to echo it inside label, i made an example which will echo in correct place and write the standard text if no num was supplied (initial)

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<br><br>
<center>
<div class="card" style="width: 40rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
    <center>
        <font size=5>Gioco dell' Indovina Numero</font><br>
    </center>
    <div id="risultato" name="risultato">
    <center>
        <label>
        <?php
            $indovina=7;
            $x = 0;
            $num=array_key_exists('num1', $_GET) ? $_GET['num1'] : false;
            if(!$num){
                echo "<b>Regole del gioco:</b> Si deve indovinare nel minor numero di tentativi un <br> numero compreso fra 0 e 99 estratto casualmente dal sistema.";
            }else{
                if ($num<$indovina){
                    echo "Il numero inserito e troppo piccolo";
                }
                else if ($num>$indovina){
                    echo "Il numero inserito e' troppo grande";
                }
                if ($num==$indovina){
                    echo "Bravo, hai indovinato";
                }    
            }
        ?>

        </label>
    </center>
    </div>
    <br>
    <form method="GET">
    <label id=tentativo>Tentativo n.1</label>
    <input type="number" id="num1" name="num1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tenta</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
<center>
</body>
```

a random number betwen x and y is one internet search, to increment x you have to increment it andsave it for example in a hidden input and each time retrieve "last x" for increment

Comment: Note that `$num=$_GET['num1'];` will produce an "Undefined index" notice when the page initially opens without the parameter. It would be better to give it a default falsey value (something like `$num=$_GET['num1'] ?? 0`);

Comment: Now a syntax error slipped in :) You have an extra semicolon here: `: false;;`.